# Is there a way to set up fuzzy string matching in spaCy EntityRuler?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition, spacy-3

I want to extract some entities from a text and I want to give spaCy a higher "grade of liberty" so that a string can be recognized even if it doesn't match perfectly.

```
text_to_parse = 'I really like stack-overflow'

ruler = nlp.add_pipe('entity_ruler', before='ner', config={"phrase_matcher_attr": "LOWER"})

patterns = [
                {'label': 'THING', 'pattern': 'stackoverflow'},
            ]

ruler.add_patterns(patterns)
```

In this case the string is not matched because of the dash (-).

I want spacy to match all the possible variants within a certain limit (for example 80% match) so that strings like "stickoverflow" or "stack-overflow" are recognized.

Usually I rely on libraries like fuzzysearch or fuzzywuzzy but I wonder if there is a way to do so in spaCy EntityRuler.

Comment: There is a PR to add support for fuzzy matching open at the moment. https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/pull/11359